# Reverse int array return wrong element

Tags: c#, arrays, reverse

Here is a simple method in C# to reverse the element of the array. For instance, if I input {1,2,3,4} the result should be {4,3,2,1}.

```
public int[] reverse(int[] array)
{
    int[] new_array = new int[array.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length-1; i++)
    {
        new_array[i] = array[array.Length-1 - i];
    }
    return new_array;
}
```

However, when I run it and give an input as `{1,2,3,4}`, it result in `{4,3,2,0}`, why does the last element become `0` instead of `1`?

Comment: Is this homework or something? Because you have in .Net `Array.Reverse()`

Comment: You've got an off-by-one error in your `for` loop. You never attempt to set the last element. *either* subtract 1 from the length *or* use `<` rather than `<=`. Not both.

Comment: **BECAUSE** logic. instead of  `i < array.Length-1` do `i < array.Length`

Comment: _"why is the last element becomes 0 instead of 1?"_ -- because you stop at the next-to-last element of the array. You want `i < array.Length`, not `i < array.Length - 1`.

Comment: BTW, is easy spoting this error by just debugging your application. Debug is your friend

Comment: Why not simply loop from end like `for (int i = array.Length-1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                new_array[i] = array[i];
            }`

Comment: Did you try debugging this before asking? If you had stuck a breakpoint and watched your loop at work you would have noticed that it only ran three times and not four. You then could have looked at the condition after the last loop and noticed why it was stopping earlier than you expected (the reason already having been given in other comments). You then could have fixed your own code. Debugging is a *really* important part of programming. Learn to do it as soon as possible. In fact, even though you know the answer do the debugging on this problem anyway.

Comment: @Mairaj Why not? Because it's incorrect. That'll just take the item from an index `i` in one array and put it in the same location in another array... that's just a copy from the last element to the first, not a reverse.

Comment: @Mairaj: because `new_array[i] = array[i];` will mean that your new array is the same as the old one. And once you fix that problem you'll realise that the code inside the loop is the same whichever way you iterate the loop (because you are setting them the same no matter which order you do them in). And at that point why do the loop backwards rather than the more familiar forwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue exists here for (int i = 0; **i < array.Length-1**; i++).
You have to use `<=` if you are comparing it with `Length-1` or use `<` sign with `Length`

Try this code.

```
public int[] reverse(int[] array)
{
    int[] new_array = new int[array.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {  
        new_array[i] = array[array.Length-1 - i];
    }
    return new_array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that you are checking the array length and subtracting one.

> for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)

This says if I is less than the length of your array minus one.  There for you will never check the last element in your array.

This may be slightly easier to understand. I am basically running my for loop backwards and keeping a counter for both the new array and the original one.

```
var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] new_array = new int[array.Length];

for (int i = array.Length -1, n=0 ; i >= 0 ; i--,n++)
{
    new_array[n] = array[i];
}
```

Comment: Might be easier to understand if you explained the differences and where the problem was that you've fixed.

Comment: Not much better. "less than or equal to"... `<=`or `<` ? Neither are you running your loop backwards, you are maintaining two indexes, one counting forwards and one counting backwards, and using the relevant index in the required array.

Comment: ack! tried to update it to fast before the -1's got out of hand :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use Linq Instead of Writing Too many lines of code

## Using

```
using System.Linq;
```

## To Reverse Array

```
var reverse = array.Reverse();
```

## Or

```
int[] reverse = array.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `array.Length-1` because this will go `beyond the index of array` so only `array.Length` is enough.

```
int[] array = new int[4] { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
int[] new_array = new int[array.Length];
for (int i = 0; i< array.Length; i++)
{
  new_array[i] = array[(array.Length - 1) - i];
}
```

Comment: This is wrong due to the reasons given in comments on the question. That is your new array and old array will be the same which is not what the question demands.

Comment: @Chris i don't see comment stating that OP wants same array to be modified.

Comment: No, but your new array is not in reverse order. Your new array is in the exact same order as the original. Also I note you've now commented on sorting. This would destroy the original ordering making it *impossible* to reverse it at that point...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = array.Length - 1,j=0; i >= 0; i--,j++)
{
  new_array[j] = array[i];
}
```

Comment: Your new array will be the same as your old one. If you had explained what the changes you made were designed to do (as you should in a good answer) then you'd have realised that it didn't do the right thing.

Comment: Very sorry for the big mistake, thanks @Chris for notifying me, I corrected my mistake.

Comment: Still could do with a verbal explanation of what you have done differently and why it would work better than the original. A good answer doesn't just provide working code but also the knowledge needed to avoid the problem in the future.